# PHP read UTF-8 CSV

Tags: php, csv, utf-8, drupal-8, drush

I have a PHP script that reads from a CSV file, the file is in UTF-8 format and the code below is treating it as ASCII. How can I change the code to read the file as UTF-8?

```
if (($handle = fopen("books.csv", "r")) === FALSE)
  throw new Exception("Couldn't open books.csv");
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
```

[EDIT]
One of the issues with my current code is that the first value on the first line always has the three bytes that identifies UTF-8 files appended at the beginning. So I guess a solution that operates on a value by value or a row by row might not be good enough?

Comment: Suggested reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Answer (score 1):

Use fgets() get file all string in variable $date, then mb_convert_encoding() convert encoding, then str_getcsv() convert string to array.

```
if (($handle = fopen("books.csv", "r")) === FALSE)
    throw new Exception("Couldn't open books.csv");

$data = "";

// get file all strin in data
while (!feof($handle)) {
    $data .= fgets($handle, 5000);
}

// convert encoding
$data = mb_convert_encoding($data, "UTF-8", "auto");

// str_getcsv
$array = str_getcsv($data);
```

Comment: $data is an array in my code, is there a way to apply this on the stream before using it in fgetcsv?

Comment: Sorry, I write the wrong variable, and I change the function.

Comment: Still not working :) the error is saying first parameter should be a string

Comment: Thanks Jin for trying to help, but this didn't remove the three mangled characters that appears in the first item on the first line

Comment: How about use fgets() get file all string in variable $date, then mb_convert_encoding() convert encoding, then str_getcsv() convert string to array.

Comment: that's pretty much what I am looking for
can you help with example code how to get from fgets into string?

Comment: same results mate, I guess convert method here is written convert from 'auto' to UTF-8 and in my case the file is already UTF-8 and PHP is not able to skip the UTF-8 identification character (first three bytes). So I am looking for a way to make PHP understand it is reading a UTF-8 file not convert the file content to UTF-8.